# Defining a specific range of values for a sliderInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Even thought there are many topics dealing with the properties of the sliderInput in Shiny, I couldn't find a solution to what I'm trying to do.

My problem is simple: I would like to adapt my code (see below) in order to create a slider with an interval of "10" (from 0 to 10, 10 to 20, 3 to 13 etc...)

```
###running example: 

ui <-basicPage(
  sliderInput("id", "Ranking",
                           min = 2, max = 60, value = c(2,15)))


server <- server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `updateSliderInput` every time the slider is changed, to enforce the interval.

The trick here is to remember previous value to update the right handler (the one that that didn't change)

```
INTERVAL = 13
value = c(2, 2 + INTERVAL)

ui <-basicPage(
  sliderInput("id", "Ranking",
              min = 2, max = 60, value = value))

server <- server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$id,{
    newvalue = input$id
    
    if(value[1] != newvalue[1] && newvalue[2] - newvalue[1] != INTERVAL)
      updateSliderInput(session, "id", value = c(newvalue[1], newvalue[1] + INTERVAL))
    
    if(value[2] != newvalue[2] && newvalue[2] - newvalue[1] != INTERVAL)
      updateSliderInput(session, "id", value = c(newvalue[2] - INTERVAL, newvalue[2]))
    
    value <<- newvalue
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Awesome ! That's exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks Hubert :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want the `step` argument inside your `sliderInput()` function. [Documentation here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/sliderInput.html). But I was having issues with that having to be able to slide to individuals numbers.

Or you could select a single input as the starting range, and add 10 to that number.

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
    sliderInput("num2", "Pick a starting Range", value = 20, min = 2, max = 60),
    textOutput("num2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$num2 <- renderText({
        paste0("Your range is ", input$num2, " to ", input$num2 +10, "!")
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer Daniel ! But ideally I would like to keep the "double head sliderInput" to define the range... I already went throught the shiny documentation but I couldn't find to achieve that ! :/

Comment: It was difficult to have the interval set to 10, but then still allow it to slide to individual numbers. let me know if you find a solution, it would be great to learn.

Comment: I will ! Thanks Daniel !